# Why the first ה in יהודה?

Tags: names, hebrew, yehuda

> וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן וַתֹּאמֶר הַפַּעַם אוֹדֶה אֶת־ה' עַל־כֵּן קָרְאָה שְׁמוֹ יְהוּדָה וַתַּעֲמֹד מִלֶּדֶת׃
>   She conceived again and bore a son, and declared, “This time I will praise the LORD.” Therefore she named him Jehudah... (Ber 29)

IMHO the root of להודות is ידה (see [WikiDictionary](https://he.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94)).

If the Torah testifies that the reason for calling Yehuda was thanking G-d, why is the first ה?

(Some Meforshim say the name resembles YKWK, but that's not the open reason of the Torah).

Comment: "Not the open reason of the Torah" If you are looking for the open reason of the Torah you already have all you're going to get.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not necessarily, maybe some could split the mane into י (like הוא) and הודה?

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume the name should be an exact match to the word it's based off of? Being based off the word doesn't mean an exact match. Most of the other names are exact matches of the words in the Passuk (i.e. Levi isn't Yelaveh Ishi, Naftali isn't Naftulai).

Comment: It could be split as something like י-ה ודה, meaning “G-d thanks/ thanks G-d”. From what I understand, ו and י can switch in root words in Hebrew.

Answer (score 4):

[R. Ovadiah Seforno](https://www.sefaria.org/Sforno_on_Genesis.29.35.1?lang=he) comments:

> שיש בזה השם אותיות השם הנכבד ועם זה לשון ההודאה ונראה שהיו כל אלה שמות של קדמונים כמו שמצינו קודם לזה יהודית בת בארי ... והיו בוחרים מהשמות הקודמים את הנופלים על הלשון המאורע:‏
>
> This name contains the letters of the Honored Name, as well as the language of gratitude. It seems that all these names were the names of people of precious generations, like we find earlier Yehudit daughter of Be'eri ... And they would choose from the old names those that had language alluding to the event.

I understand him to be saying that Leah chose a name which already existed, containing the letters of G-d's Name as well as an allusion to the concept of gratitude, in order to convey the feeling of gratitude she felt towards G-d.